Windows does not boot after deleting SBAT policy
A recent Windows update broke my Windows/Ubuntu Dual Boot
I followed the steps described in Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation to fix the dual boot


Disable Secure Boot in BIOS
Log into your Ubuntu user and open a terminal
Delete the SBAT policy with: sudo mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete
Reboot your PC and log back into Ubuntu to update the SBAT policy
Reboot and then re-enable secure boot in your BIOS.


Unfortunately, I can no longer boot into Windows (except for the debug mode / secure mode), not even with disabled secure boot (UEFI).
Does anybody know or have a hint on how to resolve it?
Further information:

how does the broken boot process look like?

While booting windows there shortly appears the additional text Bitlocker recovery is being prepared
the text disappears, a loading spinner is displayed and windows seems to boot
for a splitsecond a shell with the name winspeshl.exe appears, then a bluescreen appears (with options to boot from other sources / reboot with opening the UEFI)


sudo mokutil --list-sbat-revocations: sbat,1,2022052400, grub,2
sudo mokutil --reset + restarting the system

forwards me to Shim UEFI key management

option to open MOK management with the following options:

Continue boot, Reset MOK, Enroll key from disk, Enroll hash from disk
I have choosen Continue boot so far, which does not resolve the problem, but was unsure if this is the right place to fix the issue that I have






sudo mokutil --sb-state

result depends on the secure boot selection in the UEFI, regardless of the setting windows does not boot properly

Secure Boot enabled in UEFI: SecureBoot enabled
Secure Boot disabled in UEFI: SecureBoot disabled, Platform is in Setup Mode




My setup worked that way that it automatically started Windows and I started ubuntu by rebooting the system (if you press shift while restarting windows) and then selecting another device -> ubuntu - saved on a separate disk, only then grub was be started, otherwise it was directly booted to windows.
UEFI Boot configuration

Windows Boot Manager
USB Storage
Internal Storage
Network Boot-IPV4
Network Boot-IPV6


I tried it with Windows Boot Manager first and with Internal Storage first (bought with secure bot enabled/disabled), same result




did you try to use the UEFI bios boot device selector on startup? Usually you can select an OS that is configured in UEFI there (instead of a disk or a partition). The usual way is to press an announced key on boot to get in to that selector menu, F12 or Enter or something thelike.

A long shot. When you disabled 'secure boot' did you, perhaps, switch to CSM (legacy) mode? In that mode WIN10/11(?) will never boot but if Ubuntu has been setup in a certain way, that will. What does Ubuntu command 'mokutil --sb-state' report (append to your question) (If it crashes it indicates CSM is likely enabled.)

@cyberbrain I extended the Further information section to answer your question:

My setup worked that way that it automatically started Windows and I started ubuntu by rebooting the system (if you press shift while restarting windows) and then selecting another device -> ubuntu - saved on a separate disk, only then grub was be started, otherwise it was directly booted to windows.
UEFI Boot configuration

Windows Boot Manager
USB Storage
Internal Storage
Network Boot-IPV4
Network Boot-IPV6




@david I have extended the Further information section to answer your question:

sudo mokutil --sb-state

result depends on the secure boot selection in the UEFI, regardless of the setting windows does not boot properly

Secure Boot enabled in UEFI: SecureBoot enabled
Secure Boot disabled in UEFI: SecureBoot disabled, Platform is in Setup Mode






Bitlocker recovery suggests your WIN disk/partition is encrypted? So is it encrypted? I have a notion it attempted to get the decryption key and failed. However, the fact that Ubuntu does boot suggest it is not encrypted. Are they on different disks?  'mokutil --reset' will delete all your mok keys but you probably don't have any so it will not have any effect.

did I miss a memo? when did we start supporting WINDOWS on ASKUBUNTU?

@david Ubuntu is installed on a different disk than Windows. The Windows Partition appears to be encrypted since executing 'sudo mokutil --set-sbat-policy delete', at least I have to enter the Bitlocker key when starting Windows in Debug Mode.

One of the following actions resolved the issue for me:

Booting into Windows in the advanced mode Disable Driver Signature Enforcement and allowing an windows update by this
In a Windows CMD with admin permissions run the following command: reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecureBoot\SBAT /v OptOut /d 1 /t REG_DWORD (for details see Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation)

After doing both of these steps, booting into Windows works for me again.
